# Force C compiler for extension capital C in Eclipse CDT

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm having legacy Makefiles and would like to transfer them into Eclipse CDT Projects. Coming from windows, they have mixed .c as well as .C as extensions for C sources (while eclipse normally would treat  capital ".C" as c++ files).

As they are checked into source control I'd like to avoid the hassle of renaming the source files.

As the files are linked into the workspace, I tried renaming the link to .c (leaving the target/original file as ".C"). CDT won't care and invoke the C++ compiler. Even worse, when I right-click on the file I get the settings for (only) the C compiler but what I change is irrelevant because still the C++ compiler with the project wide C++ settings is invoked.

Now, if there are only C files in the project I can set the project C++ settings under "Miscellaneous" to use `-xc -std=c99` etc. and effectively force the g++ to behave like a proper C compiler - Which is not really beautiful and completely fails when there are other real .cpp files to be compiled as C++ within the same project.

Also, using project settings under C/C++ General/File Types and setting ".c" and ".C" to "C source file" doesn't seem to bother the CDT...

Am I overlooking something? Is this far outside the scope of CDT?

Comment: You can't rename the files?

Comment: Rename the files! That's a one-time work and can be done by a simple shell-script, including changes to source control (unless you use some rubbish GUI-only system). Anything else just calls for trouble.

Comment: I'm fairly sure the `.C` recognition is part of `gcc`, not Eclipse (much like how it compiled `.cpp` as C++ by default ... as it should!). Rename the files.

Comment: If you're moving / porting the project to a system that distinguishes case in filenames, then your best long-term bet is to update the filenames.  Eclipse is not in any way differentiated by its distinction between extensions ".C" and ".c" on machines where it is meaningful.  But perhaps there's a way to persuade your source control system to handle the mapping for you?  I don't have a specific idea here, but it might be worth looking into.

Comment: I see, thanks guys!... thought there might be some solution for the usecase but renaming would be an option here...

Comment: @TimČas, no it's eclipse that recognizes to call the C++ compiler (g++). That can be forced to behave like a C compiler with -xc however. The eclipse build log shows that it's using g++ for `.C` and `.cpp` but gcc for extension `.c`

Comment: @StefanHegny: Sure, but even `gcc` will compile in C++ mode for `.cpp` and `.C` (main difference is that `gcc` does not link `libstdc++` while `g++` does). So it definitely is the compiler (... as well; probably both).